# How to use the video file as the topic of subscription instead of any camera directly?

Tags: ros, video

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of using real time video streaming data, how to get input from the video file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258763/how-to-use-the-video-file-as-the-topic-of-subscription-instead-of-any-camera-directly?/) by [chaiein](https://answers.ros.org/users/20827/chaiein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use [image_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/image_publisher):

```
rosrun image_publisher image_publisher video.avi
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1